# On Windows 7, how can I find what a process is given the process number?

Tags: windows, solr

**Background:**

I am trying to start solr on my Windows machine.  I was able to start and stop it in a cygwin window, but got a warning message about needing lsof.  So I thought I'd see what happened if I tried starting it via the Windows command prompt.  When I did that, I got the message:

> ERROR: Process 7128 is already listening on port 8983. If this is
>   Solr, please s top it first before starting (or use restart). If this
>   is not Solr, then please choose a different port using -p PORT

**Question:**

I can't seem to figure out what Process 7128 is.

When I look in the Task Manager under Processes, it does not include Process IDs.  When I look under Services it does, but I have nothing numbered 7128

In the cygwin window where I had started and stopped solr,

```
ps -ef | grep 7128
```

and

```
ps -ef | grep solr
```

both return no results.

Note that this is not a question specifically about starting solr on Windows, I just gave that for background.  **What I want to know is how to figure out what a specific process is on a Windows machine, given a process ID.**

Comment: Task Manager includes process IDs, you just have to enable them.  Under View->Select Columns.

Comment: Thank you @HarryJohnston.  Could you enter that as an answer.  I'm sure I'm not the only one who doesn't know how to enable that.  (I did look for a way to add columns directly from the ui, but didn't think to look at the view menu.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask Task Manager to show you process IDs (and lots of other interesting stuff too).

Go to the View menu and choose Select Columns.